# duplicate for every block

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this Excel table example:

```
     A B C   D
--------------
1 |  1 a 1   x
2 |    b 1  
3 |    c 2
4 |    a 3   x
5 |  2 r 4   x
6 |    r 4   x
7 |    t 1
8 |      4 
9 |  3 a 1
10|    b 3   x
11|    c 3
12|    b 6   x
```

I need to find duplicates (marked with x in column D) for every each block, but only in the context of it's own block (a block is what is found between A1 and A4 - for 1, another block is from A5 to A8 - for 2, and so on). B1=a it's not a duplicate for B9=a, because B9 belongs to block 3 and B1 belongs to block 1. But B1 is a duplicate for B4, they are on the same block, therefore both B1 and B4 should be marked with x.

I'm struggle with dynamic range finding/composition:

**Basically I need** in column D to **find the range** (starting with position in D first not empty field in A up, and first not empty field in A down). Eg: in D4 I need to get first non empty in A is A1, and first non empty in A is A5, and construct the range as A1:A5-1.

Comment: Unless you mind a helper column this will require an array formula.  Are you okay with a helper column or do you want the array formula?

Comment: I do not mind, both ways are fine. I tried with range, but I didn't any good solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a helper column to avoid the need of an array formula:

In d2 put:

```
=IF(A2="",D1,A2)
```

Which will fill in the missing column A values:

[image]

Then in E2:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(D:D,D2,B:B,B2)>1,"x","")
```

[image]

---

If you want the array formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,ROW()))/($A$1:INDEX(A:A,ROW())<>""),1)):INDEX(B:B,IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDEX(A:A,ROW()+1):INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",B:B)))/(INDEX(A:A,ROW()+1):INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",B:B))<>""),1)-1,MATCH("zzz",B:B))),B2)>1,"x","")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I understood what have you done. Now I know kung fu :P